# Numerical differentiation of summation of implicit regions

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics, regions

I'm very new to mathematica and this forum, so I apologize for the poor formatting. I am trying to find a probability density function, given a continuous and piecewise differentiable cumulative distribution function (so taking the derivative).
The cumulative distribution function is defined by the 5 regions, which I define to be "TestRegioni" for i ranging from 1 to 5. Note that s1,s2,s3,h1,h2,h3 are all constants, and t is a time parameter with respect to x and y.

```
TestRegion1[t_]:= ImplicitRegion[(1-(x*s1))/(h1)-2*x*(s1)/(h1)<y&&y<(1-(x*s1))/(h1)&&  y>(1-(2+s2)*x)/(h2)&&h1/(x*(s1*x+h1*y))<t &&  0<x&&x<1,{{x, -2, 2}, {y, -4, 4}}]

TestCDF1[t_]:=NIntegrate[1, {x,y}\[Element]TestRegion1[t]];

TestRegion2[t_]:= ImplicitRegion[(1-(x*s1))/(h1)-2*x*(s1)/(h1)<y&&y<(1-(x*(2+s2)))/(h2)&&  y>(1-(4*s1+s3)*x)/(h3)&&h2/(x*((2+s2)*x+h2*y))<t &&  0<x&&x<1,{{x, -2, 2}, {y, -4, 4}}]

TestCDF2[t_]:=NIntegrate[1, {x,y}\[Element]TestRegion2[t]]

TestRegion3[t_]:= ImplicitRegion[ (1-(x*(4*s1+3*s3)))/(h3)-2*x*(s1)/(h1)<y&&y<(1-(x*(4*s1+s3)))/(h3)&&y>(1-(s1)*x)/(h1) - 2*x*(s1)/(h1)&&h3/(x*((4*s1+s3)*x+h3*y))<t &&  0<x&&x<1,{{x, -2, 2}, {y, -4, 4}}]

TestCDF3[t_]:=NIntegrate[1, {x,y}\[Element]TestRegion3[t]]

TestRegion4[t_]:= ImplicitRegion[ (1-(x*(2 + 3*s2)))/(h2)<y&&y< (1-(x*(4*s1+3*s3)))/h3&&  
y>(1-(s1)*x)/(h1)  - 2*x*(s1)/(h1)&&h3/(x*((4*s1+3*s3)*x+h3*y))<t &&  0<x&&x<1,{{x, -2, 2}, {y, -4, 4}}]

TestCDF4[t_]:=NIntegrate[1, {x,y}\[Element]TestRegion4[t]]

TestRegion5[t_]:= ImplicitRegion[ (1-(x*s1))/(h1)-2*x*(s1)/(h1)<y&&y< (1-(x*(2+3*s2)))/h2&&h2/(x*((2+3*s2)*x+h2*y))<t &&  0<x&&x<1,{{x, -2, 2}, {y, -4, 4}}]

TestCDF5[t_]:=NIntegrate[1, {x,y}\[Element]TestRegion5[t]]

TotalCDF[t_]:=TestCDF1[t]+TestCDF2[t]+TestCDF3[t]+TestCDF4[t]+TestCDF5[t];
```

At this point I am getting no errors. Everytime I evaluate these functions at some value t, I get a numerical value, so my functions make sense. I run into an error when I then define:

```
TestPdf[s_] := ND[TotalCDF[t],t, s];
```

This is where I am trying to take the numerical derivative of the cumulative distribution function. The error I get is:

> "DiscretizeRegion: DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region ImplicitRegion[<<2>>]."

I'm not sure why I am getting this. Each of the functions evaluate correctly. Maybe it has to do with the fact that I am working with 3 variables (x,y,t)? Maybe it has to do with syntax? My ultimate goal is to Plot the probability density function, but I can't get that far because of this error. Also, I am on version 13.3.1 for Linux x86.

Comment: I'm missing the values of `s1,s2,s3,h1,h2,h3`

Comment: The values are s1 = Cos[Pi/7], s2 = Cos[2*Pi/7], s3 = Cos[3*Pi/7], h1 = Sin[Pi/7], h2 = Sin[2*Pi/7], h3 = Sin[3*Pi/7]

Answer (score 3):

Use `?NumericQ` and `Module` to evaluate pdf as follows

```
TestPdf[s_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{s1 = 1, s2 = 2, s3 = 3, h1 = 1, h2 = 2, h3 = 3}, 
   TestRegion1[t_?NumericQ] := 
    ImplicitRegion[(1 - (x*s1))/(h1) - 2*x*(s1)/(h1) < y && 
      y < (1 - (x*s1))/(h1) && y > (1 - (2 + s2)*x)/(h2) && 
      h1/(x*(s1*x + h1*y)) < t && 0 < x && 
      x < 1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -4, 4}}];
   
   TestCDF1[t_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] TestRegion1[t]];
   
   TestRegion2[t_?NumericQ] := 
    ImplicitRegion[(1 - (x*s1))/(h1) - 2*x*(s1)/(h1) < y && 
      y < (1 - (x*(2 + s2)))/(h2) && y > (1 - (4*s1 + s3)*x)/(h3) && 
      h2/(x*((2 + s2)*x + h2*y)) < t && 0 < x && 
      x < 1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -4, 4}}];
   
   TestCDF2[t_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] TestRegion2[t]];
   
   TestRegion3[t_?NumericQ] := 
    ImplicitRegion[(1 - (x*(4*s1 + 3*s3)))/(h3) - 2*x*(s1)/(h1) < y &&
       y < (1 - (x*(4*s1 + s3)))/(h3) && 
      y > (1 - (s1)*x)/(h1) - 2*x*(s1)/(h1) && 
      h3/(x*((4*s1 + s3)*x + h3*y)) < t && 0 < x && 
      x < 1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -4, 4}}];
   
   TestCDF3[t_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] TestRegion3[t]];
   
   TestRegion4[t_?NumericQ] := 
    ImplicitRegion[(1 - (x*(2 + 3*s2)))/(h2) < y && 
      y < (1 - (x*(4*s1 + 3*s3)))/h3 && 
      y > (1 - (s1)*x)/(h1) - 2*x*(s1)/(h1) && 
      h3/(x*((4*s1 + 3*s3)*x + h3*y)) < t && 0 < x && 
      x < 1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -4, 4}}];
   
   TestCDF4[t_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] TestRegion4[t]];
   
   TestRegion5[t_?NumericQ] := 
    ImplicitRegion[(1 - (x*s1))/(h1) - 2*x*(s1)/(h1) < y && 
      y < (1 - (x*(2 + 3*s2)))/h2 && 
      h2/(x*((2 + 3*s2)*x + h2*y)) < t && 0 < x && 
      x < 1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -4, 4}}];
   
   TestCDF5[t_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] TestRegion5[t]];
   
   TotalCDF[t_?NumericQ] := 
    TestCDF1[t] + TestCDF2[t] + TestCDF3[t] + TestCDF4[t] + 
     TestCDF5[t]; {TotalCDF[s], Derivative[1][TotalCDF][s]}];

lst = TestPdf[#] & /@ Range[0, 2, .1]

T = Range[0, 2, .1];

ListLinePlot[{Transpose[{T, lst[[All, 1]]}], 
  Transpose[{T, lst[[All, 2]]}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"TotalCDF", "TestPdf"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t", ""}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

**Update 1**. In a case of parameters like `s1 = Cos[Pi/7], s2 = Cos[2*Pi/7], s3 = Cos[3*Pi/7], h1 = Sin[Pi/7], h2 = Sin[2*Pi/7], h3 = Sin[3*Pi/7]` we use `Rationalize[]` and `Interpolation[]` for simplification as follows

```
TestCDF[s_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{s1 = Rationalize[Cos[Pi/7.], 10^-16], 
    s2 = Rationalize[Cos[2*Pi/7.], 10^-16], 
    s3 = Rationalize[Cos[3*Pi/7.], 10^-16], 
    h1 = Rationalize[Sin[Pi/7.], 10^-16], 
    h2 = Rationalize[Sin[2*Pi/7.], 10^-16], 
    h3 = Rationalize[Sin[3*Pi/7.], 10^-16]}, 
   TestRegion1[t_?NumericQ] := 
    ImplicitRegion[(1 - (x*s1))/(h1) - 2*x*(s1)/(h1) < y && 
      y < (1 - (x*s1))/(h1) && y > (1 - (2 + s2)*x)/(h2) && 
      h1/(x*(s1*x + h1*y)) < t && 0 < x && 
      x < 1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -4, 4}}];
   
   TestCDF1[t_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] TestRegion1[t], AccuracyGoal -> 8,
      PrecisionGoal -> 8];
   
   TestRegion2[t_?NumericQ] := 
    ImplicitRegion[(1 - (x*s1))/(h1) - 2*x*(s1)/(h1) < y && 
      y < (1 - (x*(2 + s2)))/(h2) && y > (1 - (4*s1 + s3)*x)/(h3) && 
      h2/(x*((2 + s2)*x + h2*y)) < t && 0 < x && 
      x < 1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -4, 4}}];
   
   TestCDF2[t_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] TestRegion2[t], AccuracyGoal -> 8,
      PrecisionGoal -> 8];
   
   TestRegion3[t_?NumericQ] := 
    ImplicitRegion[(1 - (x*(4*s1 + 3*s3)))/(h3) - 2*x*(s1)/(h1) < y &&
       y < (1 - (x*(4*s1 + s3)))/(h3) && 
      y > (1 - (s1)*x)/(h1) - 2*x*(s1)/(h1) && 
      h3/(x*((4*s1 + s3)*x + h3*y)) < t && 0 < x && 
      x < 1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -4, 4}}];
   
   TestCDF3[t_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] TestRegion3[t], AccuracyGoal -> 8,
      PrecisionGoal -> 8];
   
   TestRegion4[t_?NumericQ] := 
    ImplicitRegion[(1 - (x*(2 + 3*s2)))/(h2) < y && 
      y < (1 - (x*(4*s1 + 3*s3)))/h3 && 
      y > (1 - (s1)*x)/(h1) - 2*x*(s1)/(h1) && 
      h3/(x*((4*s1 + 3*s3)*x + h3*y)) < t && 0 < x && 
      x < 1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -4, 4}}];
   
   TestCDF4[t_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] TestRegion4[t], AccuracyGoal -> 8,
      PrecisionGoal -> 8];
   
   TestRegion5[t_?NumericQ] := 
    ImplicitRegion[(1 - (x*s1))/(h1) - 2*x*(s1)/(h1) < y && 
      y < (1 - (x*(2 + 3*s2)))/h2 && 
      h2/(x*((2 + 3*s2)*x + h2*y)) < t && 0 < x && 
      x < 1, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -4, 4}}];
   
   TestCDF5[t_?NumericQ] := 
    NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] TestRegion5[t], AccuracyGoal -> 8,
      PrecisionGoal -> 8];
   
   TotalCDF[t_?NumericQ] := 
    TestCDF1[t] + TestCDF2[t] + TestCDF3[t] + TestCDF4[t] + 
     TestCDF5[t]; TotalCDF[s]];
```

Example of usage

```
lst = Table[{t, TestCDF[t] // Chop}, {t, 0, 5, .025}]
cdf = Interpolation[lst, InterpolationOrder -> 4];

Plot[{cdf[t], cdf'[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"TotalCDF", "TestPdf"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"t", ""}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: It still was unable to discretize the region because, in my code, 
s1 = Cos[Pi/7], s2 = Cos[2*Pi/7], s3 = Cos[3*Pi/7], h1 = Sin[Pi/7], h2 = Sin[2*Pi/7], h3 = Sin[3*Pi/7], and these numbers are more complex than the constants you provided.

Comment: Also, when I estimate these values to the nearest tenth, the integration fails due to the error "Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, the value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small." How do I take care of this? Especially if I want finer estimations.

Comment: @CarsonNewman Please, see Update 1 to my post.

Comment: Fantastic! And to make the orange line sharper I just have to increase the interpolation and Precision goals?

Comment: @CarsonNewman It could be better to decrease step in `lst = Table[{t, TestCDF[t] // Chop}, {t, 0, 5, .025}]`, the main error coming from here. Use for example,  `lst = Table[{t, TestCDF[t] // Chop}, {t, 0, 5, .005}]`. Don't pay attention to `PrecisionGoal` up to, `{t, 0, 5, .0000001}`  .